# Why doesn't the disk filter in my Fisher & Paykel dishwasher ever dry?

Tags: dishwasher, clog

When I remove the plastic dishware grate from the drawer and remove the disk filter with the arrow, water pools here and never dries.

Any advice on how to fix this? It looks like there are special screws and a regular tool won’t work to take out the other parts in this area to check for debris blocking drainage…

Comment: It would help if you'd tell us what model you have, or at least post a photo. We're a bit in the dark.

Comment: Does your owner's manual say that this area _should_ be dry between cycles?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my dishwasher, there is a low point, sump, where the water collects.  This is under the filter/grate.  It is NOT possible for  the pump to pump every bit of water out.  So, this water never dries.  Just keep the grate clean and run a clean cycle periodically.